# How can I mount a Ring Pro on this door post?

Tags: door-frame, doorbell

My wife has had her heart set on getting a Ring Pro video doorbell since someone at work demonstrated theirs. We picked one up from Lowes today, but discovered we had an issue when we got home and looked at installing it.

[image: Image of the doorbell in its frame, perpendicular to the porch]

Somehow, we'd missed that the doorbell is set into the post at a perpendicular angle. The people with Ring Pro support are sending a bracket, but I don't think the result will be able to be mounted without blocking the screen door. I can't find any handy spot where the post is fastened into the door frame such that we might drill holes to reroute the wires.

[image: Top of the Post] [image: Bottom of the post]

It kind of looks like there's some amount of separation, but I haven't found any nails or screws. Is there any advice on how I might get this doorbell hung?

The inside of the post does not appear to be hollow:
[image: Image of the recess where the old doorbell sits] [image: recess of the old doorbell with the flash on]

Comment: start by detaching the doorbell switch from the door post

Comment: @jstola: Is there something I should be looking for in the process?

Comment: space inside the door post .... you do not have all the available information about the  door post until you take off the push button switch and look inside the hole where the wires are

Comment: @jsotola: Ah. Thank you. I was just trying to make sure that you were doing the "follow the instructions for installation" when I was looking for a different question.

Comment: @jsotola: Unfortunately, it looks like they only added enough space for the wires.

Comment: the picture does not show anything .... you have to probe inside the hole to determine if there is space behind the boards

Comment: @jsotola: Indeed, the pictures don't do it justice. But yes, I have probed the interior and it's solid wood other than the bit that goes off to the right into the interior of the house. The prior owner was a DIYer, so I would not be surprised if this was his work. Unfortunately, he's been dead a few years, so I can't ask him any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost two years later, I realized that I never came to an answer here. The kit that Ring provided consisted of angle wedges to turn the doorbell to better focus on the area in front of the door, which did not help me, as it even more blocked the door. What I wound up doing is drilling an additional hole into the front of the post to run wires through, bought some more bell wire, and spliced additional length to the front, where I mounted the doorbell. My primary method string the wire involved using a more stiff wire to initially poke from the side to the front, and then attaching the bell wire to that to pull it through. The only issue I've faced is that I had to seal off the hole to the side to prevent humidity from affecting the bell's operation.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for coming back to provide your answer. I realized that this question was quite old, but "drill a hole from the front to meet the existing hole" would have been my answer, too.